# Make git push a no-op

Tags: git

I have a handy sbt plugin which does a bunch of software release and lifecycle management stuff, and one of the things it does is automatically push the commits it makes to the configured upstream branch.

Unfortunately, that upstream is temporarily down. I can just push the commits later, so for now, I'd like my sbt plugin to just no-op when it does a `git push`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you need to modify your plugin.

Comment: @StephenC So you're saying that there's no way to make `git push` a no-op?

Comment: Also depends on how it's  calling `git`. If it's enough to alias out `push` in your personal git config, or the repo's, then it's really simple.

Comment: No.  But I'm saying that modifying your plugin to make the push a selectable or configurable option (or to ignore failure) sounds a better idea than hacking your git integration to make it a no-op.

Comment: @tripleee Go on, I'm listening :)

Comment: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases

Comment: Hmmm, actually http://superuser.com/questions/276079/disable-specific-git-commands-in-a-particular-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the push url for the remote to "."

```
git config remote.origin.pushurl .
```

then when the real one's back, undo the redirect:

```
git config --unset remote.origin.pushurl
```

If your branches are tracking differently-named upstream branches this will cause problems, in that case just make a nonce repo:

```
git clone --template '' -s --bare . ../nonce
git config remote.origin.pushurl ../nonce
```

which will isolate the namespaces.  You can just delete the nonce repo when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple wrapper for the `git` command which rejects any push. Here is a fairly trivial Bash function.

```
git () {
    case $1 in
      push)
        echo "git: push disabled" >&2
        return 1 ;;
    esac
    command git "$@"
}
```

This is crude -- it does no option parsing, so e.g. `git --verbose push` bypasses the `case` check. But for your stated problem, it probably doesn't need to be any more sophisticated.